# Joomla 3.4.1. How to fix “Could not instantiate mail function" in Koparent

Tags: joomla-3.4

I keep on getting the error 'Could not instantiate mail' in an module called Koparent that I use for my booking system in Joomla. At first I thought it might just be an issue with Koparent, then I searched around and found that it's likely an issue with my Joomla settings, see below.

Can someone please help me fix this

[image: joomla settings]

[image: error message]

Comment: if you are on Joomla 3.4.1 upgrade immediately. - make sure you have a tested and workable backup in place first.

Comment: @ffrewin, do you think this is the cause for the error?

Comment: no I don't say so - i m just saying 3.4.1 is outdated and vulnerable

Comment: Since you are having errors changing the Global configuration, I recommend changing via FTP to SendMail and SMTP and see if error persists.  Also, in FTP, go to  /libraries/phpmailer/  and make sure the folder exists.  I had it somehow disappear on one site and just had to re-upload from core Joomla download.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is the server you site is on doesn't allow sending on behalf of emails not registered or that server and therefore fails.

Make sure the from email is a real email address which is on the server of your site.

Answer (score 1):

Seams like your server doesn't support phpmail.

You can try to switch to an alternativ method like "sendmail" or "smtp"

You can also use the "Send Test Mail" button below the settings to test them.

More info about the email configuration in Joomla : https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Global_configuration

Comment: Pierre, thanks for responding. phpmail was working a on the 22nd June, as I was able to send email. I can't say how long after that date it stopped working. I have tried 'Send Test Mail' with smtp, and sendmail but nothing works. Any other ideas?

Comment: I should mention that when I'm in global configuration mode whenever I attempt to make a change I get the message: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. As a result no changes are made.

Comment: Hello All,

I have just tried to register on my site. I should get an email letting me that someone is trying to register, however I didn't get an email, therefore I dont think this problem is particularly an issue with Koparent.